# Specifying version of Sonar plugin

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a Maven multi-module project and as part of my build I execute

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

I get some unexpected behaviour with a particular maven plugin that there is no need to go into here and after a lot of debugging and trial-and-error, I decided to tweak the particular plugin in question to add some debugging. The plugin in question is the sonar javascript plugin (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript).

I cloned the git repo, incremented the version to 2.16 (latest available is 2.15), modified a logging statement, executed mvn install. Then I went back to my project hoping that when I executed mvn sonar:sonar it would simply pick up the latest version of this plugin available on my local repo. It didn't. I tried adding this to my pom:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.javascript</groupId>
        <artifactId>javascript</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
      </plugin>
```

Still nothing. The logging statement is unchanged.

So how can I get the sonar execution to pick up my locally installed version of the plugin?

Comment: Consider reporting your problem in the [SonarQube Google group]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube)

Comment: The SonarQube JavaScript plugin is not at all a Maven plugin. Could you start by reporting your initial issue and the relating error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install the plugin on your SonarQube server.

Changing the plugin source means that you'll be on your own from their on though. If you've got legitimate issues/feedback with the JavaScript Plugin, then reach out to their maintainers on the [SonarQube Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube). Constructive feedback will be heard, you'll get a chance to contribute directly to the `sonar-javascript` project, and the community we'll be able to benefit from your improvement(s) (rather than you flying solo with custom changes).

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas, I am not yet sure whether this will be a case of improvements to the actual plugin or not, but of course if I find such a thing I will submit it rather than proceed with a customised plugin. Step one is to figure out what's wrong...